# How is it written deposit money by coin?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

Recently I want to change my massive coin into money . I heard about I can change coin to bank account money at ATM in Tokyo , so I went to bank ATM . But I couldn't choose English language on screen so I came back without doing anything .

I want to know what will it written of deposit coin into bank account in Japanese ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, finding a way to switch the panel to English must be **a lot** easier than anything written below. Just press <kbd>ENGLISH</kbd> or <kbd>LANGUAGE</kbd> on screen. If the touchscreen did not work, try another machine.

Next, check if your ATM has an opening like this:

[image: 硬貨]

If it doesn't, the machine does not support coins. ATMs in convenience stores generally do not support coins.

Next, here are minimum words needed:

- 預入{あずけいれ} / 預け{あずけ}入れ{いれ} / 入金{にゅうきん}: deposit (putting money into your account)
- 硬貨{こうか}: coin
- 紙幣{しへい}: bill (paper money)
- 確認: confirmed / proceed

Next, [this](https://nomad-saving.com/66334/) is a step-by-step instruction to deposit coins using Mitsubishi UFJ Bank's ATM.

Lastly, remember that the coin slot may not open unless you explicitly push the `硬貨 / COINS` button on screen. (Maybe because it's mechanically delicate?)

Comment: Thank for editing ! I just edited by the help of google translate :>